# Relationship in Families

Tags: family-law

My moms brother, Uncle Tom, marries a woman (Liz).

Liz has children from a previous marriage (Tracy and Anthony) who become my uncles step-children. Tracy marries Zachary.

What is Zachary's legal relationship to me?

Is Zachary legally identified as a relative?

Comment: I don't think this can be answered in the abstract. For purposes of emergency family-related leave, the federal government has one definition; an insurance policy could have a different one. For those federal purposes, even a close friend could count. Cousin marriage laws apply to genetically related people. Inheritance law would be distinct. Probably, though, that would be deemed "no relation".

Answer (score 1):

I'm going to guess and say Zachary is your ***step-cousin-in-law***.

I agree with @user6726's comment that you need to provide more context (the purpose or statute/s) under which you seek an opinion about being a *legal* relative. But it seems pretty clear Zachary is not related by blood. And only through marriage. If that makes any difference.